# How to run an external command as a specific user in PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache, impersonation

I thought of suPHP but that's not what I need. It doesn't serve to my purposes to run the whole PHP script as a different user. I just need to run one single linux command line as a different user.

Is it possible?

Comment: by suPHP you mean phpsuexec? // http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/suexec.html

Comment: I know suPHP and suEXEC, but I dont know what phpsuexec is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the [shell_exec](http://php.net/shell_exec) function and sudo

**edit**: seeing as sudo prompts for a password, you'd might wanna use [proc_open](http://php.net/proc_open), which allows you to use pipes. See [this comment](http://php.net/proc_open#83635) for how to create a custom password pipe.

Comment: Try proc_open then. See the first example on the manual page that I linked to, for how to use pipes.

Comment: @SteveKemp - That seems like a bad idea for a forward facing web server. Maybe a setuid program would be a better choice.

Comment: I would assume you would __only__ allow the single command you wanted to be executed as the random-user to be executed, not open things up so that anything could be executed as any user!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should try another approach. The "setuid".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid

Basically you ask the file to run as it's owner, not the program.

Comment: In the link it says: "Due to the increased likelihood of security flaws, many operating systems ignore the setuid attribute when applied to executable shell scripts". A shell script is what I need to run. Does Linux have this restriction?

Comment: Not by default, but a script is only permitted to run setuid if its interpreter is also setuid.

Comment: What if I compile a C program who in turn executes a shell command and I set the setuid flag for that C program?  would it bypass that restriction?

Comment: Your C program would need to call `setuid(geteuid())` to get out of setuid mode, but yeah, that would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that users CRON to execute the script. If this is a web application then you are limited to the Apache/Nobody user with limited permissions. If this just needs to run at a certain time I would use CRON.

Another approach is [Sticky Bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit)