# Setuid on scripts with C wrapper

Tags: php, c, linux, centos, suid

i've just want to use a php script with root permission with a C wrapper like this [tutorial](http://goodworkaround.com/node/39).

ls -l :

```
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 6466 Aug 15 03:07 createConfig
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  102 Aug 15 04:23 test.php
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  822 Aug 14 21:35 index.php
```

createConfig.c :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    system("/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/test.php");
    return 0;
}
```

test.php :

```
<?php
mkdir("/root/ourDir");
?>
```

index.php :

```
<?php
exec("/var/www/html/createConfig");
?>
```

but when run index.php on browser i got this error :

```
sh: /var/www/html/createConfig: Permission denied
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you do an [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) or an [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) ?

Comment: Basile, are there any examples? I've tried them but didn't quite work. The params weren't passed correct and other issues.... it was long time ago to remember

Comment: Also see [How to run an external command as a specific user in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1898393/608639)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put `setgid(getegid()); setuid(geteuid())` before calling `system()`.

As a side-note, the way the file permissions are set up in your example, your "solution" is totally unsecure. Any user can change the contents of the .php script to be run by that setuid C program, and then use the C program to execute the changed contents as `root`.